# Ошибка компиляции, неправильная запись условия

Tags: c++

Гутен абенд.

Вчера начал изучение плюсов, написал код -> получил ошибку. Не могу понять, в чем проблема. Помогите, пожалуйста) Ошибка во второй части, на уровне цикла If

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    double a;
    cout << "Введите число a: ";
    cin >> a;
    if((a > 2 && a <= 5) || (a > 20 && a < 35))
        cout << "Введенное число принадлежит диапазону";
    else cout << "Введенное число НЕ принадлежит диапазону";

    double h;
    double q;
    cout << "Введите число h: ";
    cin >> h;
    if(sqrt(h) <= 3.75)
        q = (1 + h) / (pow(h, 4));
        cout << q;
    else q = log (h);
        cout << q;
}
```

Comment: "цикла If"??? "написал код -> получил ошибку" - где текст ошибки?

Answer (score 2):

Форматируйте правильно:

```
if(sqrt(h) <= 3.75)
    q = (1 + h) / (pow(h, 4));
cout << q;
else q = log (h);
cout << q;
```

Теперь видите? Вы забыли фигурные скобки...

Тут вам не Python :)

Кстати, общие `cout << q;` лучше вынести за пределы `if-else`.

Answer (score 2):

Формально в синтаксисе языков C и С++ ветви условной инструкции `if` обязаны состоять только из *одной-единственной* инструкции. А вы попытались вписать туда две. Это не допускается.

Если вам необходимо сформировать ветвь `if`, включающую *несколько* инструкций, вам следует сначала "упаковать" эти инструкции в скобки `{ ... }`, тем самым превратив их в *одну* составную инструкцию.